# Is there a package in either PSTricks or Tikz to draw the following diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks

I took the following figure from [JSON](http://json.org/) official site.

[image]

Is there a package to do it easily?

Anyway, what is the name of this diagram?

Comment: If it had arrows, I'd say it's a deterministic finite state automaton.

Comment: @TH If I had to guess, I'd say that the arrows are implied and it is a DFA, albeit an "artistic" representation of one.

Comment: TiKZ `chains` library. See the fourth tutorial in the TikZ manual.

Comment: @Aaron: As per Herbert's answer, it appears that these syntax diagrams are supposed to be for CFGs, so I guess they aren't DFAs (although the language for this one is clearly regular).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

that are so-called railroad diagrams for the syntax and can be set with simple nodes and loops:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\def\CBox#1{\pscirclebox[fillcolor=green!20,fillstyle=solid]{\bfseries#1}}
\def\PBox#1{\psframebox[fillcolor=green!20,fillstyle=solid]{\bfseries\shortstack{#1}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(0,-5)(13,1)
\psset{linewidth=1.5pt,linearc=0.3}\psline{|-|}(13,0)
\psforeach{\iA}{0,1,..,13}{\pnode(\iA,0){O\iA}}
\ncloop[angleB=180,loopsize=-1]{O0}{O2}\ncput{\CBox{--}}
\rput(3,0){\CBox{0}}
\ncloop[angleB=180,loopsize=-1.75]{O2}{O6}\ncput[npos=2.3]{\PBox{digit\\1-9}}
\rput(5.5,-2.5){\rnode{A}{\PBox{digit}}}\ncloop[angleB=180,loopsize=0.75]{A}{A}
\ncloop[angleB=180,loopsize=0.75]{O6}{O9}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

No package but a  tutorial: Diagrams as Simple Graphs in the pgfmanual page 60. You only need to change (modify) some styles

Answer (score 2):

I am sure you can find an example on [www.texample.net](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/)

that you can modify to suit your needs. I am not aware of a package that does precesily the job.

Comment: Here it is: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/diagram-chains/

Answer (score 1):

I believe these are called "syntax diagrams".  I don't know about a package, but there is a tool called [syngen](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/syngen/) on ctan that will generate those.  It uses LaTeX picture environment, so the results are not as good looking as if you used tikz or pstricks, but maybe you could modify the code to produce some tikz code instead.