# How to draw curved paths

Tags: tikz-pgf, paths

I'm trying to do this picture :

[image]

I have a problem to draw the curved paths.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[scale=0.5,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usetkzobj{all} 
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows,positioning,fit,calc,backgrounds}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\tikzset{
   b/.style={
       draw,
       rectangle,
       rounded corners=2ex,
       minimum height=0.2cm,
       minimum width=1in,
       align=center,
       font=\small},
   c/.style={
      draw,
      rectangle,
      rounded corners=2ex,
      minimum height=0.5in,
      minimum width=2in,
      align=center,
      rotate=-90,
      font=\large},
   ar/.style={
      rounded corners=2ex,
      ->,
      >=latex},  
   myarrow/.style args={#1 colored by #2 and #3}{
      -stealth,
      line width=#1,
      #2,
      postaction={draw,-stealth,#3,line width=(#1)/3,
      shorten <=(#1)/3,
      shorten >=2*(#1)/3}, 
      },
   toptext/.style={    % <-- New
      above,
      text width=6cm,
      align=center,
      font=\large}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\node (string) [b] {string};
\node (number) [b, below=0.3 cm of string] {number};
\node (object) [b, below=0.3 cm of number] {object};
\node (array) [b, below=0.3 cm of object] {array};
\node (true) [b, below=0.3 cm of array] {true};
\node (false) [b, below=0.3 cm of true] {false};
\node (null) [b, below=0.3 cm of false] {null};

\draw  (string.west) -- ++(-70pt,0pt);
\draw  (string.east) -- ++(70pt,0pt);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a package in either PSTricks or Tikz to draw the following diagram?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14133/is-there-a-package-in-either-pstricks-or-tikz-to-draw-the-following-diagram)

Comment: Yeah I will look at it. We should change it's title to that question! I haven't found that question when asked mine.

Comment: The answer here use pst-node. I use tikz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some ideas:

1. Define coordinates named `left` and `right` (for example) which contain the coordinate at which the curve starts and ends at the sides of `(string)` node. For example:

   ```
   \coordinate (left) at ($(string.west)+(-20pt,0pt)$);
   \coordinate (right) at ($(string.east)+(20pt,0pt)$);
   ```
2. Use the syntax `(left) -- +(2ex,0) |- (number)` for example, to draw a polygonal line between the point named `left`, another point 2ex to its right, and a L shaped line descending up to the level of node named `number`, and finally to that node. The trick is to use `rounded corners=2ex` for this polygonal, so that the radius is equal to the distance to the second point.
3. Similarly, the curve at the right side is drawn with `(number) -| ($(right)+(-2ex,0)$) -- +(right)`
4. In fact, both parts can be combined in a single `\draw` command, unless you want arrows for the first half but not for the second half, for example.
5. All the above has to be done for each node below `(string)`, so it can be easily iterated in a loop.

So the code will be:

```
\coordinate (left) at ($(string.west)+(-20pt,0pt)$);
\coordinate (right) at ($(string.east)+(20pt,0pt)$);

\draw  ($(left) +(-30pt, 0)$) -- (string);
\draw  (string.east) -- ($(right) + (30pt,0)$);

\foreach \token in {number, object, array, true, false, null} {
    \draw[rounded corners=2ex] (left) -- +(2ex,0) |- (\token) -| ($(right)+(-2ex,0)$) -- (right);    
}
```

Producing:

[image: Result]

**Note:** the rest of the code is not shown because is identical to the one you provided, except that I changed `rounded corners=1ex` (instead of 2ex) for the `b/.style`. Using 2ex caused some artifacts because this radius is greater than half the height of the boxes.